# Android API 16 NDK cwctype and string build errors

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.1-jelly-bean

Android NDK newbie question.

I'm trying to compile a library using the Android NDK. I'm building for **API16** and get the following errors in the build:

> In file included from /Volumes/MacAirExt/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cwchar:107:
>   /Volumes/MacAirExt/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cwctype:88:9: **error: no member named 'iswblank' in the global namespace; did you mean 'isblank'?
>   using ::iswblank;**

AND

> In file included from /Volumes/MacAirExt/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/string:438:
>   /Volumes/MacAirExt/Android/android-ndk-r10e/sources/cxx-stl/llvm-libc++/libcxx/include/cwchar:132:9: **error: no member named 'vfwscanf' in the global namespace
>   using ::vfwscanf;**

etc

If I build for **API21**, I don't get any build errors. I guess the library (LibMailCore) is utilising string functions only available in the latest Android API.

Any experts out there know how to get around this?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same issue, just as some added information: this only happens with c++_static (works fine with gnustl_static)

Comment: I set it to gnustl_static, but still getting the same error ... So did you solve this issue ? And how ?